# Error en pantalla btn is null

Tags: javascript, vue.js, null

Me arroja el error en pantalla de que btn es null, adjunto el codigo javascript, estoy usando el framework vu3 gracias..

```
const esconder_editar=()=>{
    let btn:any
    btn = document.querySelector(".btn_editar")
    btn.style.display="none" 
} 
esconder_editar();
```

codigo html

```
<h3>REGISTRO DE ROLES</h3>
        <div>
            <input type="text" v-model="nombre">
        </div>
        <div class="btn">
            <div class="btn_mas">
                <button @click="registrar()">Añadir</button>
            </div>
            <div class="btn_editar">
                <button @click="editar()">Guardar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: ¿Estás llamando a `esconder_editar()` nada más definir la función? Si es así, podría darse el caso de que se esté llamando antes de que se haya renderizado el botón (por lo que sería null)

Comment: Prueba con `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => { // código... });`

Comment: muchas gracias...